# If $\mathbb{A}^{1} \backslash \{0\} = \mathbb{P}^{1} \backslash \{[1:0],[0:1]\}$ then what's $\mathbb{A}^{2} \backslash \{0\}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is the closest way to write $\mathbb{A}^{2} \backslash \{0\} \subset \mathbb{P}^{2}$ the same way as $\mathbb{A}^{1} \backslash \{0\} = \mathbb{P}^{1} \backslash \{[1:0],[0:1]\}$? For the projective line either coordinate can be the projective coordinate so I would like to know if it's possible to write the projective plane that way too.

I've thought about using the notation for projective varieties, which by that I mean writing the union of vanishing sets each polynomials restriction to each coordinate chart. For obtaining the projective line I gave the vanishing set of the polynomial $x_1$ restricted to the coordinate chart of $x_{0}$ is unioned with the vanishing set of the polynomial ${x_0}$ restricted to the coordinate chart of $x_{1}$. I think that is what to obtain it by anyway because the polynomial $x_{0}$ restricts to $1$ on the coordinate chart of $x_{0}$ and $1$ vanishes on $\{\emptyset\}$ which isn't a set that is omitted in the definition that I used. The errors for doing the same as for the projective line is unioning the vanishing sets of the polynomials $x_0,x_1,x_2$ doesn't take out the whole projective line in any coordinate chart and takes out more than the origin of the affine plane. I can't think of another way to try even if I remove all the points such as $0,x_{1},x_{2}$ in the coordinate chart of $x_{0}$ then if $x_{1}$ is the projective coordinate  too many points would be removed.

Comment: First of all, your notation for points on $\mathbb P^1$ is confusing. We typically write homogeneous coordinates like $(1:0)$ or $[1:0]$. Secondly, if we identify $0 \in \mathbb A^1$ with $(0:1) \in \mathbb P^1$, then the analogue of the point at infinity $(1:0) \in \mathbb P^1$ in one dimension higher is the entire line at infinity given by $Z=0$ (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$), assuming we take $(X:Y:Z)$ as coordinates on $\mathbb P^2$.

Comment: @TabesBridges you are right I forgot them but they are in now.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{P}^1 = \mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{[1:0],[0:1]\}$?

Comment: It was supposed to be this: $\mathbb{A}^{1} \backslash \{0\} = \mathbb{P}^{1} \backslash \{[1:0],[0:1]\}$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want $\mathbb{A}^2 - (0, 0)$ as a subscheme of projective space? There is an open immersion $\mathbb{A}^2 - (0, 0) \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2 $, and then you can compose that with an open immersion $\mathbb{A}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$

Comment: I mean if $\mathbb{A}^{2} \backslash \{0\}$ is an open subspace the same way $\mathbb{A}^{1} \backslash \{0\}$; which sets are the vanishing sets that $\mathbb{A}^{2} \backslash {0}$ is the complimentary set of?